# ModelChoiceFilter not working using django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I am using Django 1.8, I want to list all the merchant using the django_filters, I have two models Shipment and Merchant

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
        merchant_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,db_index=True,verbose_name='Merchant ID',null=True,blank=True)


class Shipment(models.Model):
          merchant_related = models.ForeignKey(Merchant,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="merchant related to shipment")
```

I have the shipments list page with all the shipments and related merchants, I need to add the merchant filter in shipment_list.html with all merchant created ids as choices.

```
filter.py

class MerchantFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    merchants = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Merchant.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = ['merchants']

views.py
def search_merchant(request):
    merchant_filter = MerchantFilter(request.GET,queryset=Merchant.objects.all())
    context = {

        'filter':merchant_filter

    }

    return render(request,"shipment_list.html",context)


In shipment_list.html:

<div>
      <form method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I am getting the search button.But not getting the merchant created ids as choices.Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: First things first, `django-filter` is now only listed as supporting `Django 1.11+`. So are you using a suitably older version which would support `Django 1.8`?  Secondly, what is actual output/source between your `<form>` tags if you inspect it. Is anything other than the button being added at all?

Comment: Button is getting added and form is blank when i inspect it. I want to display the merchant created id as choices i.e as dropdown

Comment: Ok, so [from the docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter) it appears that the model in your filter `Meta` class needs to be the related model, in your case, `Shipment`, instead of `Merchant`. This will then let you filter `shipments` by `merchant`.